# Rails + Radio Buttons + AJAX: How to render partial on radio button click?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a check out form for my ecommerce site. It has radio buttons for shipping options (express, standard, etc) and I want it to show a dynamic value of `<%= shipping_delivered_day %>` to appear inside the `p.label_delivery_date` tag next to the button the user clicks using AJAX. This is my html:

```
<% @shipping_services.each do |ship| %>
  <%
    shipping_service = ShippingService.find_by_name(ship.shipping_service)
    ship_id_value = ""+shipping_service.id.to_s
  %>
  <label class="reverse-label">
    <span class="check">
        <%= radio_button :shipment, :desired_shipping_method, ship_id_value, :checked => "checked" %>
        <%= radio_button :shipment, :desired_shipping_method, ship_id_value "%>
    </span>

    <span class="label">
      <%= shipping_service.description %>
      <p class="label_delivery_date" ></p>
    </span>
    <span class="label">
      <%= shipping_service.description %>
    </span>
  </label>

<% end %>
```

I know I can do an `:onclick` option on my radio button, but that would just send me to a javascript file. I need to be able to pass in my dynamic `shipping_delivered_day` value, so I need rails to handle it. How would I send JS request from a radio button click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby/Rails actually provides a pretty slick way of doing this. All you have to do is have your radio button call a javascript function on click, and then put the partial render in that function, like so:

```
<script>
function render_partial() {
  $('#partial-area').html('<%=j render :partial => "partial" %>')
}
</script>

<%=  radio_button :model, :field, :value, :onclick => "render_partial();" %>
<div id="partial-area"></div>
```

This will render the given partial into the 'partial-area' div when the radio button is clicked. For multiple partials, just have multiple functions acting on the same div. In your specific instance, you'll want your partial to contain some code that will determine your shipping delivery date. You could render the partial with locals (`render :partial => "ship_3day", :locals => {:p => @product}`) and have your partial return the appropriate result (`<%= p.shipping_delivered_day %>`).