# show data in div on radio button click through ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to show selected data by user on ajax call.

Scenario is that I have two radio buttons, and when user clicks on either one it should show the respective data on the right side, in the response div.

**HTML:**

```
<form id="package-call" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div class='pakges'>
        <div class="sub-pakge">
            <div class="sub-pakge-content">
                <span class="content-title">North America</span><br>
                <span class="content-title">Basic</span>
                <div class="content-time">150 Minutes</div>
                <span class="content-price">Rs.500</span>
                <div class="pakges-radio"><input type="radio" name="package" id="package" >    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-pakges">
            <div class="sub-pakges-content">
                <span class="content-title">North America</span><br>
                <span class="content-title">Max</span>
                <div class="content-time">400 Minutes</div>
                <span class="content-price">Rs.200</span>
                <div class="pakges-radio"><input type="radio" name="package" id="package">   </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**AJAX:**

```
$("#package").click(function(e){ 

    $.ajax( {
        type: "POST",
        url: "package _selection.php",
        data: $('#package_call').serialize(),
        success: function( response ) {}
    });

});
```

**This is the div where i want to show my response:**

```
<div class="form-results">
    <div class="rslt-content-main">
        <div class="rslt-content">Selected Pakages / Bolts</div>
        <div id="package_response"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And these are the result div's that i want to get through ajax call from package _selection.php and want to display respectively

```
<div class="radio_one_rslt">
    <div>voice:</div><br />
    <div>IDD Asia - Rs 200</div>
</div>

<div class="radio_two_rslt">
    <div>voice:</div><br />
    <div>IDD Asia - Rs 500</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a great start! Don't give up!

Comment: At what point are you having problems?

Comment: When i click on the radio it do not send any call so i cannot move further beyond this point

Comment: Having more that one element with the same `id` is a bad practice.

Comment: I don't know how to do this right off the top of my head, however I can say that you will need an event listener.

Comment: i am infact confused in it and dont know now how to get my hands free from it

Comment: See my answer below. If you are still not able to make the request, make sure you are putting the listener inside `$(document).ready()`

Comment: its in document,ready but its not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For listening to a radio button, use the 'change' event

```
$("#package").on('change', function(e){
```

Then, assuming your response is the HTML you want to append, append it in your success callback

```
$.ajax( {
  type: "POST",
  url: "package _selection.php",
  data: $('#package_call').serialize(),
  success: function( response ) {
    $('#package_response').append(response);
  }
});
```

A blog post for reference: http://blog.stephenborg.com/?p=37

Comment: can any one send me just a link where there is a demo on just call ajax on radio click

Comment: Can you provide some more information about what happens when you click the radio button? Does the handler work at all or does the ajax call just not work? This is another approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16863443/rails-radio-buttons-ajax-how-to-render-partial-on-radio-button-click

Comment: when i click on radio nothing happened and i want that at least event should generate

Comment: i am also looking for ajax call/event when click on radio but shocked that i couldnt find any thing as i am not very good at searching

Comment: i want to solve this problem step by step and first step is generate ajax call on click so i cannot move forward and i also just alert on click nothing happens as well

Comment: its the code which is not working $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#package").click(function() {
            
   alert('here');
        });

    });

Comment: `$('#package')` is also not a good listener because it only refers to the first one. Use a class or separate IDs for each button.

Comment: can you send me any refrence link for ajax call on radio click as i am not good at searching

Comment: added it to my answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36491/discussion-between-kwk-stack-and-cole-pilegard)

Comment: i catch the problem cause finally now trying to fix it

Comment: and finally i solved the issue with the little help of javascript here is the solution may be someone else some time would face the same problem so i want to share it with you function select_packages(){
 var opt_checked = document.getElementById('package').checked;
 if(opt_checked == true){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "final_result.php",
    data: $('#package_call').serialize(),
    success: function( response ) {
    $('#package_response').append(response);
  }
});
  }
 }

Comment: and then call this function in onchange event like <input type="radio" name="package"  onchange="select_packages()" id="package" >

Comment: thanks every one for coopration and specially you @cole Pilegard hats off 4 u

Comment: @kwk.stack No problem. Please accept the answer if it was helpful, although it looked like you got pretty far on your own!