# Rendering Partials with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a list of items loaded into a radio button list.  When one of those items is clicked, I want to display additional information about that item in a div elsewhere on the page.  For example, I am listing different types of rooms for a hotel. If the user clicks on a particular room type, I want to display the estimated cost of that room in a different diff.

After much googling about, I came across this post: [Rails + Radio Buttons + AJAX: How to render partial on radio button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16863443/rails-radio-buttons-ajax-how-to-render-partial-on-radio-button-click).  It gave me the idea to use partials; however the answer didn't quite provide enough guidance for me so I did a little reading on partials.  I ended up with the following:

**In my main view**

```
<% @available_rooms.each do |rt| %>
    <div class="radio-item">
        <%= b.radio_button :room_type, rt.id, :class => 'rb_room_type inline', :onclick => 'render_room_info();' %>
        <%= content_tag :span, rt.name  %>
        <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="<%= rt.description %>">
            <%= image_tag "tooltip.png", :class=>"tooltip-icon" %>
        </a>
     </div>
 <% end %>

<div id="estimated-due" class="group column-2">
</div>
```

**My partial view named _room_details.html.erb**

```
<span class="booking-est-cost">Estimated Cost: &pound;<%= rt.room_price %></span>
```

**Javascript File**

```
function render_room_info() {
    $("#estimated-due").html("<%= j render :partial => 'room_details', locals => { :rt => @rt } %>");
}
```

From everything I've read, this should work.  However, when I click on a radio button, it renders out the literal html string in the div:

```
<%= j render :partial => 'room_details', locals => { :rt => @rt } %>
```

So clearly the rails code isn't firing.  Since javascript is client side, I guess this makes sense but I can't really figure out how to make this work.  I read a few articles that talked about doing ajax requests but they all seemed like serious overkill for what I need to do (not to mention overly complex).  Am I missing something simple? I just need to render out the value of one or two fields on click of a radio button.

Just as a reference, I'm using Rails 4.2.

Comment: Where/what is "Javascript File"?

Comment: If you only have a small amount of extra information to display when the radio button is clicked - and don't want to bother with AJAX - you could just have the div present in the page but hidden using CSS (e.g. `display:none;`).  Then when the radio button is clicked have a JavaScript function display the div.

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit an ajax request to a rails route. Because you are doing this from a radio button, you could do something like:

```
function render_room_info() {
    $.ajax({
          url: room_rate?rt=xx,
          dataType: "script"
        });
}
```

Then the action at the route specified above needs to respond to a ajax request:

```
#some logic to get set the @rt variable
@rt = params[:rt]

respond_to do |format|
      format.html {
        }
      format.js {
        }
    end
```

and then you put your instructions to replace with a partial in a js file based on the name of the controller action e.g. `room_rate.js`

```
$("#estimated-due").html("<%= j render :partial => 'room_details', locals => { :rt => @rt } %>");
```

Comment: So do I need to create an entirely different controller just for this? A room_rate controller that also has related views? Or do you mean to use the existing controller and room_rate (or something equivalent) would be the action defined in the controller with a related view? Just wanting to clarify.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. It does not need to be its own controller, just an action with a related view (*.js file is the view for the ajax request) and of course a route to that action. Then use the url to that route in the $.ajax call.

Comment: I updated the answer to reference controller action, not controller